# Get text between two special characters in a line using shell

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a line which comes from a file via:

```
cat aaa.txt | grep "HIJK"
```

Output gives:

```
HIJK="My name is HIJK"
```

I need to get the text `My name is HIJK` into a variable in a shell script.

I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
cat aaa.txt | grep "HIJK" | sed -n '/\"/,/\"/p'
```

Comment: grep "HIJK" aaa.txt

will avoid the use of cat

Comment: Your question says you want all the text "My name is HIJK" in the variable. Please confirm this is indeed what you mean. Your subject says "text between two special characters". What/where are these special characters?

Comment: UUOC, UUOG. `sed -n 's/^HIJK="\(.*\)".*/\1/p' aaa.txt` or `grep HIJK aaa.txt | cut -d \" -f2`

Answer (score 1):

use `IFS` for this

```
$ IFS=\= read var1 var2 <<< $(grep "HIJK" aaa.txt)
$ echo $var1
HIJK
$ echo $var2
"My name is HIJK"
$ var2="${var2%\"}" // remove double quotes on both sides
$ var2="${var2#\"}"
$ echo $var2
My name is HIJK
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, to add to the mix, solve it using `awk`:-

```
awk -F'"' '$1 ~ /HIJK/ {print $2}' aaa.txt
```

which prints:-

```
My name is HIJK
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed` with basic regex:

```
$ grep "HIJK" aaa.txt | sed 's/.*="\(.*\)"/\1/g'
My name is HIJK
```

`sed` with extended regex:

```
$ grep "HIJK" aaa.txt | sed -r 's/.*="(.*)"/\1/g'
My name is HIJK
```

The double quotes don't need escaping, as they are already inside single quotes (and hence will be treated as literals, as they are not special).

You could also use `grep -oP` if your version of `grep` supports this:

```
$ grep "HIJK" aaa.txt | grep -oP '(?<==").*(?=")'
My name is HIJK
```

If your initial `grep` is guaranteed to be the text before the `=`, you could cut this down to:

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=HIJK=").*(?=")' aaa.txt
My name is HIJK
```

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this problem in two steps:

**1.** After you `grep`ed it for the pattern, use `awk` to strip off the part before the = sign:

```
awk -F = '{print $2}'
```

**2.** Then strip off the " signs with an old Unix trick using `rev` and `cut`:

```
rev | cut --complement -c 1 | rev | cut --complement -c 1
```

**Summary:**
To put it all together, you can use the following command to achieve the resulting string:

```
grep "HIJK" filename | awk -F = '{print $2}' | rev | cut --complement -c 1 | rev | cut --complement -c 1
```

If you want to put the result in a variable, you can use this command:

```
VARIABLE="$(grep "HIJK" filename | awk -F = '{print $2}' | rev | cut --complement -c 1 | rev | cut --complement -c 1)"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work (only `sed`, no `grep`):

```
VAR=$(sed 's/.*"\([^\"]*HIJK[^\"]*\)\"/\1/g' aaa.txt)
```

Content of the variable:

```
echo $VAR
My name is HIJK
```

Answer (score 0):

If the desire is to set the variable as specified in aaa.txt, then you can just use eval.

E.g.:

```
$ grep HJIK aaa.txt
HJIK="My name is HJIK"
$ eval $(grep HJIK aaa.txt)
$ echo $HJIK
My name is HJIK
```

Comment: What happens if the file contains `HJIK="My name is $(rm -rf slash)"`

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
VAR=$(sed -n '/HIJK=/s/HIJK="\([^"]*\)"/\1/p' aaa.txt)
```

Don't print any lines by default (`-n`), but on lines matching `HJIK=` (`/HJIK=/`), replace `HJIK="(something not containing double quotes)"` with `(something not containing double quotes)`: `s/HIJK="\([^"]*\)"/\1/` and then print them - the `p` flag.